# Get HTML5 file details with javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

How are you supposed to access a file's details **after** the file has been selected through an html file select input?

I have this html:

```
<input type="file" id="file-select" name="attachment"/>
```

Using some jquery, I can view the file's details when the file input is changed like this:

```
$('#file-select').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var name = file.name;
    var size = file.size;
    var type = file.type;
    console.log("File: " + file);
    console.log("Name: " + name);
    console.log("Size: " + size);
    console.log("Type: " + type);
});
```

Is there a way to access these details outside the 'change' event? For example, I figured this would work:

```
$("#file-select").files[0].name
```

but it doesn't, and gives me an 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because jQuery has no files property as part of the object, that is off the DOM element.

```
$("#file-select").get(0).files[0].name
```

or

```
$("#file-select")[0].files[0].name
```

---

Basic example showing how to access the input on a button click

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  
    var ol = $("ol").empty();

    var files = $("#file-select").get(0).files; 
  
    for(var i=0; i<files.length;i++) {

        var file = files[i];
        var name = file.name;
        var size = file.size;
        var type = file.type;

        $("<li>" + name + " - " + size + " - " + type + "</li>").appendTo(ol);
      
      }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file-select" name="attachment"/>
<button>List</button>
<ol></ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I didn't know about the "get" method. When I pull up the DOM tree though, I don't see any elements under that <input> element. Is there another way I can see the uploaded file and its info in the DOM tree?

Comment: What do you mean in the DOM tree/ pulling up?

Comment: I mean, once I've selected the file, if I open the developer window and look at all the DOM elements, it looks exactly the same as before I selected the file. I'm just wondering how you knew using the ".get(0)" method would work, because I don't see anything different in the <input> element.

Comment: The `get()` method has nothing to do with getting the files. Do you know the difference between a jQuery object and a DOM HTML Element Node? `.get(0)` gets rid of the jQuery object and gives you the raw DOM which is just like what you are doing when you use `this` in the onchange. You can not inspect the files in the DOM inspector.